# SQL Server hierarchy with parent id and child id

Tags: sql, sql-server, parent-child, hierarchy

[image: Click here for results image]

I would like to generate the 'hierarchy id' values which is denoted in red. The value is the lowest level of id in the hierarchy. The highest level of hierarchy is 'ALL Service Groups' and the lowest level is 'LL800_GB05'. They are related with Parent ID and ID. The attached image is only a sample set.

Update-- I have formed a relationship and lineage. Now i know the highest member of Hierarchy.I want to associate the lowest childID for each row in a new column. I tired doing an inner join on Parentid and ID but didnot workout completely. I tried a crossjoin but didnot workout. Below is the data for insertion

```
CREATE TABLE CO1 (
    PARENTID INT,
    ID INT,
    CID VARCHAR(38) ,
    Depth INT,
    Lineage VARCHAR(28) 
);
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (1105,48039,'All Service Groups',0,'/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (48039,48100,'Ovhd Service Groups',1,'/48039/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (48039,133686,'Network Services',1,'/48039/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (48039,133689,'Shared Services',1,'/48039/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (48039,133692,'SW Security K-12 Monitoring',1,'/48039/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (48039,133695,'Print Services Group',1,'/48039/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (48039,138170,'Miscellaneous Service Groups',1,'/48039/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (48039,48109,'Total Shared Services Security',1,'/48039/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (48100,140656,'K909_GB00',2,'/48039/48100/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (48100,140631,'K909_GG00',2,'/48039/48100/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (48100,140634,'K909_GA02',2,'/48039/48100/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (48100,48045,'G0000002',2,'/48039/48100/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (48109,48089,'GH010001',2,'/48039/48109/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (48109,48090,'GH010002',2,'/48039/48109/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (48109,48091,'GH010003',2,'/48039/48109/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (48109,48092,'GH010004',2,'/48039/48109/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (48109,48093,'GH010005',2,'/48039/48109/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (48109,48094,'GH010006',2,'/48039/48109/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133686,133647,'Network Voice Services',2,'/48039/133686/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133686,48106,'Network Data Services',2,'/48039/133686/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133689,133634,'Server Hosting Services',2,'/48039/133689/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133689,48105,'Mainframe Services',2,'/48039/133689/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133689,133640,'Desktop Support & Application Services',2,'/48039/133689/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133692,133682,'K12 Monitoring',2,'/48039/133692/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133695,48108,'Total Print Services',2,'/48039/133695/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133695,140641,'K909_GZ00',2,'/48039/133695/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (138170,138165,'Help Desk',2,'/48039/138170/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (138170,138166,'DS',2,'/48039/138170/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (138170,138167,'SCS',2,'/48039/138170/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (138170,138168,'IT Plan and Admin',2,'/48039/138170/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (138170,138162,'K909XGA01',2,'/48039/138170/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (138170,138163,'Surplus',2,'/48039/138170/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133682,133681,'K909_GM00',3,'/48039/133692/133682/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133682,133683,'K909_GM01',3,'/48039/133692/133682/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133682,133684,'K909XGM01',3,'/48039/133692/133682/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133647,133657,'Telecom Project Management',3,'/48039/133686/133647/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133647,133660,'Telecom Wiring',3,'/48039/133686/133647/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133647,133663,'Shared CENTREX',3,'/48039/133686/133647/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133647,133649,'Total VoiP',3,'/48039/133686/133647/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133647,133651,'Local Services Telco',3,'/48039/133686/133647/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133647,133654,'Long Distance Telco',3,'/48039/133686/133647/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133634,48076,'K909_GG40',3,'/48039/133689/133634/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133634,48077,'K909_GG41',3,'/48039/133689/133634/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133634,48078,'K909_GG42',3,'/48039/133689/133634/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133634,48079,'K909_GG43',3,'/48039/133689/133634/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133634,48080,'K909_GG44',3,'/48039/133689/133634/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133634,48081,'K909_GG45',3,'/48039/133689/133634/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133634,48082,'K909_GG46',3,'/48039/133689/133634/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133634,48083,'K909_GG47',3,'/48039/133689/133634/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133634,133638,'K909_GG48',3,'/48039/133689/133634/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133634,133679,'K909_GG49',3,'/48039/133689/133634/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133634,133680,'K909_GG07',3,'/48039/133689/133634/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133634,138164,'K909_GG04',3,'/48039/133689/133634/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133640,133642,'Application Services',3,'/48039/133689/133640/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133640,133644,'Total Desktop Support',3,'/48039/133689/133640/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (48105,48067,'K909_GG11',3,'/48039/133689/48105/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (48105,48068,'K909_GG12',3,'/48039/133689/48105/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (48105,48069,'K909_GG13',3,'/48039/133689/48105/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (48105,48070,'K909_GG14',3,'/48039/133689/48105/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (48105,48071,'K909_GG10',3,'/48039/133689/48105/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (48106,133667,'Total DTO Internet',3,'/48039/133686/48106/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (48106,133670,'MetroNet',3,'/48039/133686/48106/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (48106,133673,'Router Management',3,'/48039/133686/48106/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (48106,133676,'Firll / VN Management',3,'/48039/133686/48106/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (48106,48103,'Total WAN',3,'/48039/133686/48106/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (48108,48095,'K909_GK00',3,'/48039/133695/48108/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (48103,48066,'K909_GD05',4,'/48039/133686/48106/48103/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133642,48074,'K909_GG30',4,'/48039/133689/133640/133642/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133644,133678,'K909_GG21',4,'/48039/133689/133640/133644/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133644,48072,'K909_GG20',4,'/48039/133689/133640/133644/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133649,48053,'K909_GB05',4,'/48039/133686/133647/133649/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133651,48054,'K909_GB06',4,'/48039/133686/133647/133651/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133654,48055,'K909_GB07',4,'/48039/133686/133647/133654/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133657,48049,'K909_GB01',4,'/48039/133686/133647/133657/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133657,133656,'K909_GB08',4,'/48039/133686/133647/133657/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133660,133659,'K909_GB09',4,'/48039/133686/133647/133660/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133660,48050,'K909_GB02',4,'/48039/133686/133647/133660/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133663,48051,'K909_GB03',4,'/48039/133686/133647/133663/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133663,48052,'K909_GB10',4,'/48039/133686/133647/133663/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133667,48056,'K909_GD01',4,'/48039/133686/48106/133667/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133667,48057,'K909_GD07',4,'/48039/133686/48106/133667/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133670,48058,'K909_GD02',4,'/48039/133686/48106/133670/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133673,48060,'K909_GD03',4,'/48039/133686/48106/133673/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133676,48061,'K909_GD04',4,'/48039/133686/48106/133676/');
INSERT INTO CO1 VALUES (133676,48062,'K909_GD06',4,'/48039/133686/48106/133676/');
```

and SQL statements i tried are below

```
SELECT A.[PARENTID]
      ,A.[ID]
      ,A.[CID]
      ,A.[Depth]
      ,A.[Lineage],B.ID as HierID
  FROM [dbo].[CO1new] A

  inner join  [dbo].[CO1new] as B on (A.ID =B.PARENTID)

where A.PARENTID in ( 1105,133686,133647,133657,133660,133663,133649,133651,133654)

  order by 5
```

Any inputs please

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Also can you please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I know I just answered a similar question.  you are looking for the decendant and a recursive cte will be what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your request.  Here is the code to build the full hierarchy.
This results were constructed from the 85 rows of hierarchy that you supplied in your question.

I still don't know what you mean by Lowest Level.  There are many lowest levels.  I added a field IsParent which indicates whether or not a point is a parent/roll-up...  Zero indicates a leaf or bottom node.

```
;With cteOH (id,ParentID,Lvl,CID,SortSeq) 
 as (
     Select id,ParentID,Lvl=1,CID,SortSeq = cast(concat(id,'>') as varchar(500)) from CO1 where ParentID=1105
     Union All
     Select h.id,h.ParentID,cteOH.Lvl+1,h.CID ,SortSeq = cast(concat(cteOH.SortSeq,h.id)+'>' as varchar(500)) FROM CO1 h INNER JOIN cteOH ON h.ParentID = cteOH.id 
    ),
    cteR1  as (Select id,SortSeq,r1=Row_Number() over (Order by SortSeq) From cteOH),
    cteR2  as (Select A.id,r2 = max(B.r1) From cteOH A Join cteR1 B on (B.SortSeq Like A.SortSeq+'%') Group By A.id)
    Select B.R1
          ,C.R2
          ,A.Lvl
          ,A.ID
          ,A.ParentID
          ,A.CID
          ,IsParent = iif(R1<>R2,1,0)
     Into  dbo.CO1_Hier                 -- << Storing Results of Hier For Ease of Use
     From  cteOH A
     Join  cteR1 B on (A.ID=B.ID)
     Join  cteR2 C on (A.ID=C.ID)
```

Results of Hierarchy Build

```
R1                   R2                   Lvl         ID          ParentID    CID                                    IsParent
-------------------- -------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -------------------------------------- -----------
1                    85                   1           48039       1105        All Service Groups                     1
2                    31                   2           133686      48039       Network Services                       1
3                    18                   3           133647      133686      Network Voice Services                 1
4                    5                    4           133649      133647      Total VoiP                             1
5                    5                    5           48053       133649      K909_GB05                              0
6                    7                    4           133651      133647      Local Services Telco                   1
7                    7                    5           48054       133651      K909_GB06                              0
8                    9                    4           133654      133647      Long Distance Telco                    1
9                    9                    5           48055       133654      K909_GB07                              0
10                   12                   4           133657      133647      Telecom Project Management             1
11                   11                   5           133656      133657      K909_GB08                              0
12                   12                   5           48049       133657      K909_GB01                              0
13                   15                   4           133660      133647      Telecom Wiring                         1
14                   14                   5           133659      133660      K909_GB09                              0
15                   15                   5           48050       133660      K909_GB02                              0
16                   18                   4           133663      133647      Shared CENTREX                         1
17                   17                   5           48051       133663      K909_GB03                              0
18                   18                   5           48052       133663      K909_GB10                              0
19                   31                   3           48106       133686      Network Data Services                  1
20                   22                   4           133667      48106       Total DTO Internet                     1
21                   21                   5           48056       133667      K909_GD01                              0
22                   22                   5           48057       133667      K909_GD07                              0
23                   24                   4           133670      48106       MetroNet                               1
24                   24                   5           48058       133670      K909_GD02                              0
25                   26                   4           133673      48106       Router Management                      1
26                   26                   5           48060       133673      K909_GD03                              0
27                   29                   4           133676      48106       Firll / VN Management                  1
28                   28                   5           48061       133676      K909_GD04                              0
29                   29                   5           48062       133676      K909_GD06                              0
30                   31                   4           48103       48106       Total WAN                              1
31                   31                   5           48066       48103       K909_GD05                              0
32                   57                   2           133689      48039       Shared Services                        1
33                   45                   3           133634      133689      Server Hosting Services                1
34                   34                   4           133638      133634      K909_GG48                              0
35                   35                   4           133679      133634      K909_GG49                              0
36                   36                   4           133680      133634      K909_GG07                              0
37                   37                   4           138164      133634      K909_GG04                              0
38                   38                   4           48076       133634      K909_GG40                              0
39                   39                   4           48077       133634      K909_GG41                              0
40                   40                   4           48078       133634      K909_GG42                              0
41                   41                   4           48079       133634      K909_GG43                              0
42                   42                   4           48080       133634      K909_GG44                              0
43                   43                   4           48081       133634      K909_GG45                              0
44                   44                   4           48082       133634      K909_GG46                              0
45                   45                   4           48083       133634      K909_GG47                              0
46                   51                   3           133640      133689      Desktop Support & Application Services 1
47                   48                   4           133642      133640      Application Services                   1
48                   48                   5           48074       133642      K909_GG30                              0
49                   51                   4           133644      133640      Total Desktop Support                  1
50                   50                   5           133678      133644      K909_GG21                              0
51                   51                   5           48072       133644      K909_GG20                              0
52                   57                   3           48105       133689      Mainframe Services                     1
53                   53                   4           48067       48105       K909_GG11                              0
54                   54                   4           48068       48105       K909_GG12                              0
55                   55                   4           48069       48105       K909_GG13                              0
56                   56                   4           48070       48105       K909_GG14                              0
57                   57                   4           48071       48105       K909_GG10                              0
58                   62                   2           133692      48039       SW Security K-12 Monitoring            1
59                   62                   3           133682      133692      K12 Monitoring                         1
60                   60                   4           133681      133682      K909_GM00                              0
61                   61                   4           133683      133682      K909_GM01                              0
62                   62                   4           133684      133682      K909XGM01                              0
63                   66                   2           133695      48039       Print Services Group                   1
64                   64                   3           140641      133695      K909_GZ00                              0
65                   66                   3           48108       133695      Total Print Services                   1
66                   66                   4           48095       48108       K909_GK00                              0
67                   73                   2           138170      48039       Miscellaneous Service Groups           1
68                   68                   3           138162      138170      K909XGA01                              0
69                   69                   3           138163      138170      Surplus                                0
70                   70                   3           138165      138170      Help Desk                              0
71                   71                   3           138166      138170      DS                                     0
72                   72                   3           138167      138170      SCS                                    0
73                   73                   3           138168      138170      IT Plan and Admin                      0
74                   78                   2           48100       48039       Ovhd Service Groups                    1
75                   75                   3           140631      48100       K909_GG00                              0
76                   76                   3           140634      48100       K909_GA02                              0
77                   77                   3           140656      48100       K909_GB00                              0
78                   78                   3           48045       48100       G0000002                               0
79                   85                   2           48109       48039       Total Shared Services Security         1
80                   80                   3           48089       48109       GH010001                               0
81                   81                   3           48090       48109       GH010002                               0
82                   82                   3           48091       48109       GH010003                               0
83                   83                   3           48092       48109       GH010004                               0
84                   84                   3           48093       48109       GH010005                               0
85                   85                   3           48094       48109       GH010006                               0

(85 row(s) affected)][1]][1]
```

> Now, this is the cool part!

**
I created some random data at the NON-PARENT or leaf level in table Co1_Trans

The following query illustrates how to roll the data up via the range keys

```
Select H.R1
      ,H.R2
      ,H.Lvl
      ,H.ID
      ,H.ParentID
      ,H.CID
      ,H.IsParent
      ,NestedDesc      = space((H.Lvl-1)*2)+H.CID
      ,Records         = count(*)
      ,MinVal          = min(SomeValue)
      ,MaxVal          = max(SomeValue)
      ,AvgVal          = Avg(SomeValue)
      ,SomeValue       = sum(SomeValue)
      ,SomeOtherValue  = sum(SomeOtherValue)
 From dbo.CO1_Hier H
 Join (Select _R1=B.R1,A.* From [dbo].[CO1_Trans] A Join dbo.CO1_Hier B on (A.ID=B.ID)) B
   on (B._R1 between H.R1 and H.R2)
 Group By H.R1
      ,H.R2
      ,H.Lvl
      ,H.ID
      ,H.ParentID
      ,H.CID
      ,H.IsParent
  Order By H.R1
```

The results are displayed here
[image]

Now, let's say that you only wanted to show Levels 1 and 2.   Let's use the same query as before, but add a where clause ..  **Where H.Lvl<3**

```
      ...
      ,SomeOtherValue  = sum(SomeOtherValue)
 From dbo.CO1_Hier H
 Join (Select _R1=B.R1,A.* From [dbo].[CO1_Trans] A Join dbo.CO1_Hier B on (A.ID=B.ID)) B  on (B._R1 between H.R1 and H.R2)
 Where H.Lvl<3
 Group By H.R1
      ,H.R2
      ,H.Lvl
      ...
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you know the lowest descendant at the beginning of your query then walk up through a recursive cte which would make this easier and more fool proof.  If you don't know the lowest level then you need to walk down the tree to find it. So you have to know/be able to figure out either the top parent or the bottom descendant.

This answer works but only because there is only 1 descendant at the lowest level which seems very unlikely to me!  But that is the issue, how would you choose which heirarchyid to put at the parent when there is more than 1 descendant at the lowest level?  Or would you want the parent etc. to be duplicated which coincidentally this query will do in that case.

```
;WITH cteRecursive AS (
    SELECT
       GreatestAncestorId = Id
       ,Id
       ,ParentId
       ,Level = 0
    FROM
       @Table t
    WHERE
       ParentId = 1105

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
       c.GreatestAncestorId
       ,t.Id
       ,t.ParentId
       ,Level = c.Level + 1
    FROM
       @Table t
       INNER JOIN cteRecursive c
       ON t.ParentId = c.Id
)

, cteLowestDecendent AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 Id AS LowestDecendatId, GreatestAncestorId
    FROM
       cteRecursive
    ORDER BY
       Level DESC
)

SELECT`enter code here`
   l.LowestDecendatId
   ,r.*
FROM
    cteRecursive r
    INNER JOIN cteLowestDecendent l
   ON r.GreatestAncestorId = l.GreatestAncestorId
```

There are a couple of interesting techniques on this post: [SQL Hierarchy - Resolve full path for all ancestors of a given node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37869753/sql-hierarchy-resolve-full-path-for-all-ancestors-of-a-given-node/37873054#37873054) check them out for more detail on walking up and down the tree or creating a different type of heirarchyid all together.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use range keys on my hierarchies.  With the range keys (R1 & R2), you can select and/or aggregate data without the need for recursive queries.  Also, you know all ancestors and/or descendants.  Now, I normally store my hierarchies with the ranges keys and rebuild as necessary.

This technique supports variable depth (or jagged) hierarchies with ease.

In the following example, normally the top node(s) have a parent of null, but the sample data did not, so in the anchor query I have **where ParentID=1105**

```
Declare @Table table (id int,ParentID int,Name varchar(50))
Insert Into @Table (ID,ParentID,Name) values
(48039,1105,'All Services'),
(133686,48039,'Ntw Services'),
(133647,133686,'Ntwk voice Services'),
(133649,133647,'Ntwk VOIP'),
(48053,133649,'LL800_GB05'),
(999999,133649,'Dummy to Illustrate multiple children')


Declare @GetID int = 48053   -- Any Desired ID

;With cteOH (id,ParentID,Lvl,Name,SortSeq) 
 as (
     Select id,ParentID,Lvl=1,Name,SortSeq = cast(concat(id,'>') as varchar(500)) from @Table where ParentID=1105
     Union All
     Select h.id,h.ParentID,cteOH.Lvl+1,h.Name ,SortSeq = cast(concat(cteOH.SortSeq,h.id)+'>' as varchar(500)) FROM @Table h INNER JOIN cteOH ON h.ParentID = cteOH.id 
    ),
    cteR1  as (Select id,SortSeq,r1=Row_Number() over (Order by SortSeq) From cteOH),
    cteR2  as (Select A.id,r2 = max(B.r1) From cteOH A Join cteR1 B on (B.SortSeq Like A.SortSeq+'%') Group By A.id)
    Select HierarchyID = F.ID  -- Added to to fullfill request
          ,B.R1                -- Included to Illustrate Range Keys
          ,C.R2                -- Included to Illustrate Range Keys
          ,A.Lvl               -- Included to Illustrate Level of Node
          ,A.ID
          ,A.ParentID
          ,A.Name
     From  cteOH A
     Join  cteR1 B on (A.ID=B.ID)
     Join  cteR2 C on (A.ID=C.ID)
     Join  cteR1 F on (F.ID=@GetID and F.R1 between B.R1 and C.R2)
```

Returns

```
HierarchyID R1  R2  Lvl ID      ParentID    Name
48053       1   6   1   48039   1105        All Services
48053       2   6   2   133686  48039       Ntw Services
48053       3   6   3   133647  133686      Ntwk voice Services
48053       4   6   4   133649  133647      Ntwk VOIP
48053       5   5   5   48053   133649      LL800_GB05
```

Notice my dummy ID is not displayed

Now in this sample, I included **Join cteR1 F** so you can go Back UP the hierarchy

@Matt pointed out that I misunderstood the request, so I wanted a chance to redeem myself and introduce the the Range Key technique.

Answer (score 0):

A simplified Roll-To-Top

```
Declare @Table table (id int,ParentID int,Name varchar(50))
Insert Into @Table (ID,ParentID,Name) values
(48039,1105,'All Services'),
(133686,48039,'Ntw Services'),
(133647,133686,'Ntwk voice Services'),
(133649,133647,'Ntwk VOIP'),
(48053,133649,'LL800_GB05')


Declare @GetID int = 48053   -- Any Desired ID


;With cteOH (Lvl,HierarchyId,id,ParentID,Name) 
  as (
      Select Lvl=0,HierarchyId=@GetID,id,ParentID,Name from @Table where ID=@GetID
      Union All
      Select cteOH.Lvl-1,HierarchyId=@GetID,h.id,h.ParentID,h.Name FROM @Table h INNER JOIN cteOH ON cteOH.ParentID = H.id 
     )
     Select HierarchyId,id,ParentID,Name from cteOH Order by Lvl
```

Returns

```
HierarchyId id      ParentID    Name
48053       48039   1105        All Services
48053       133686  48039       Ntw Services
48053       133647  133686      Ntwk voice Services
48053       133649  133647      Ntwk VOIP
48053       48053   133649      LL800_GB05
```

When I ran the FULL Hier Build on your data supplied, the results were immediate and as follows:

```
R1                   R2                   Lvl         ID          ParentID    CID
-------------------- -------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- --------------------------------------
1                    85                   1           48039       1105        All Service Groups
2                    31                   2           133686      48039       Network Services
3                    18                   3           133647      133686      Network Voice Services
4                    5                    4           133649      133647      Total VoiP
5                    5                    5           48053       133649      K909_GB05
6                    7                    4           133651      133647      Local Services Telco
7                    7                    5           48054       133651      K909_GB06
8                    9                    4           133654      133647      Long Distance Telco
9                    9                    5           48055       133654      K909_GB07
10                   12                   4           133657      133647      Telecom Project Management
11                   11                   5           133656      133657      K909_GB08
12                   12                   5           48049       133657      K909_GB01
13                   15                   4           133660      133647      Telecom Wiring
14                   14                   5           133659      133660      K909_GB09
15                   15                   5           48050       133660      K909_GB02
16                   18                   4           133663      133647      Shared CENTREX
17                   17                   5           48051       133663      K909_GB03
18                   18                   5           48052       133663      K909_GB10
19                   31                   3           48106       133686      Network Data Services
20                   22                   4           133667      48106       Total DTO Internet
21                   21                   5           48056       133667      K909_GD01
22                   22                   5           48057       133667      K909_GD07
23                   24                   4           133670      48106       MetroNet
24                   24                   5           48058       133670      K909_GD02
25                   26                   4           133673      48106       Router Management
26                   26                   5           48060       133673      K909_GD03
27                   29                   4           133676      48106       Firll / VN Management
28                   28                   5           48061       133676      K909_GD04
29                   29                   5           48062       133676      K909_GD06
30                   31                   4           48103       48106       Total WAN
31                   31                   5           48066       48103       K909_GD05
32                   57                   2           133689      48039       Shared Services
33                   45                   3           133634      133689      Server Hosting Services
34                   34                   4           133638      133634      K909_GG48
35                   35                   4           133679      133634      K909_GG49
36                   36                   4           133680      133634      K909_GG07
37                   37                   4           138164      133634      K909_GG04
38                   38                   4           48076       133634      K909_GG40
39                   39                   4           48077       133634      K909_GG41
40                   40                   4           48078       133634      K909_GG42
41                   41                   4           48079       133634      K909_GG43
42                   42                   4           48080       133634      K909_GG44
43                   43                   4           48081       133634      K909_GG45
44                   44                   4           48082       133634      K909_GG46
45                   45                   4           48083       133634      K909_GG47
46                   51                   3           133640      133689      Desktop Support & Application Services
47                   48                   4           133642      133640      Application Services
48                   48                   5           48074       133642      K909_GG30
49                   51                   4           133644      133640      Total Desktop Support
50                   50                   5           133678      133644      K909_GG21
51                   51                   5           48072       133644      K909_GG20
52                   57                   3           48105       133689      Mainframe Services
53                   53                   4           48067       48105       K909_GG11
54                   54                   4           48068       48105       K909_GG12
55                   55                   4           48069       48105       K909_GG13
56                   56                   4           48070       48105       K909_GG14
57                   57                   4           48071       48105       K909_GG10
58                   62                   2           133692      48039       SW Security K-12 Monitoring
59                   62                   3           133682      133692      K12 Monitoring
60                   60                   4           133681      133682      K909_GM00
61                   61                   4           133683      133682      K909_GM01
62                   62                   4           133684      133682      K909XGM01
63                   66                   2           133695      48039       Print Services Group
64                   64                   3           140641      133695      K909_GZ00
65                   66                   3           48108       133695      Total Print Services
66                   66                   4           48095       48108       K909_GK00
67                   73                   2           138170      48039       Miscellaneous Service Groups
68                   68                   3           138162      138170      K909XGA01
69                   69                   3           138163      138170      Surplus
70                   70                   3           138165      138170      Help Desk
71                   71                   3           138166      138170      DS
72                   72                   3           138167      138170      SCS
73                   73                   3           138168      138170      IT Plan and Admin
74                   78                   2           48100       48039       Ovhd Service Groups
75                   75                   3           140631      48100       K909_GG00
76                   76                   3           140634      48100       K909_GA02
77                   77                   3           140656      48100       K909_GB00
78                   78                   3           48045       48100       G0000002
79                   85                   2           48109       48039       Total Shared Services Security
80                   80                   3           48089       48109       GH010001
81                   81                   3           48090       48109       GH010002
82                   82                   3           48091       48109       GH010003
83                   83                   3           48092       48109       GH010004
84                   84                   3           48093       48109       GH010005
85                   85                   3           48094       48109       GH010006

(85 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Appreciate all your responses. Do i have to know the highest level of hierarchy and lowest level to create a hierarchy. Or can i just use your logic so that it can find the tree.  Thanks

Comment: For the simplified Roll-to-top, you only need to know the id in question, and it will show the full path from top - idX.  Now in my other solution it generates a full hierarchy with Range Keys... Very powerful

Comment: In the second solution, remove the final join   Join  cteR1 F on (F.ID=@GetID and F.R1 between B.R1 and C.R2) and HierarchyID = F.ID

Comment: John,In to use your other solution you have put an @GetID int = 48053 . For mine solution to generate a hierarchy i will not be able to determine the lowest level and highest level.  Thanks

Comment: In my second example, I added a dummy node on the hierarchy which is a peer to LL800_GB05.   In this case what would you consider the "Lowest" point in the Hierarchy

Comment: John,The code ran for 2.5 hrs and still was running so i had to terminate and  go with an  approach on finding the highest member of hierarchy and its lineage. Thanks

Comment: 2.5 hours?  I would have killed it at 2.5 seconds.  How big is your hierarchy?  Are you running it against a transaction table or a DISTINCT list of ID,ParentID, Name

Comment: Another possibility is that you have loop in your hierarchy

Comment: It takes 17 seconds to build a 124,722 point hierarchy with range keys.

Comment: OK, I forced a loop in the sample data, and the process ends after maximum recursion is hit.  Almost immediately..   This leads me to believe that you were it against a transaction table and NOT against  a distinct list of id, ParentID, Name

Comment: Ran it against you updated question (Table C01)  same results as the demo immediatly

Comment: John, the hierarchy table has 140 rows.Can you please post the code which generated the 124k point hierarchy.The result i was expecting would be of around the same number or more rows with the lowest ID in another column so that i can join this to the fact table.  Thanks

Comment: I added an answer which begins with "As per your request."